# PL/SQL Pattern Matching

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a string e.g 'Sunday was great $day for me
                     $20170912'

I want the output to be 'Sunday was great $20170912' i.e wherever dates available that should remain

How can I achieve this?

Comment: First define the rules for determining how you figure out what part of the string to get rid of (or keep).  Do all strings have 2 words starting with dollar signs?  Could there be a variable number of dollar sign words? Will the date word always be the last? etc Show some more sample strings from actual data too if possible.  We could find a solution for the single example you give but it may not be flexible for other cases.

Comment: I want to keep the dates e.g $20170910 wherever dates(any) are there in the string but apart from the dates wherever we get '$' after this whatever text is there it should be removed in that particular line

Comment: Do you also need to check that the eight-digit string is a valid date (and not, for example, represent February 30)? Is the date always followed by space or end-of-string, or can it also be followed by other characters (comma, period etc.)?

Comment: No, no need to check the eight-digit string is a valid date it should only have 8 digits after $ .And date can by followed by special characters ( , etc

Comment: OK - but not by letters? Perhaps $20170319ABC is not even possible in your data; but by what you said, it should be deleted (because it is NOT a "date" preceded by $ and followed by space or special character or end-of-string, it is followed by a letter).

Answer (score 1):

See my comment to your post above.  That said, here's a solution that will work only for the exact example you gave using regexp_replace().  Maybe it will give you some ideas.

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
      select 'Sunday was great $day for me $20170912' from dual
    )
    select 
      regexp_replace(str, '^(.*)( \$.*)( \$20\d{2}[01]\d[0-3]\d)$', '\1\3' ) After
    from tbl;

AFTER
--------------------------
Sunday was great $20170912

SQL>
```

Note that my regex for testing the last 8 digits is a date is not very robust either and needs improving.  It only checks for a year in the 21st century, etc.  It is just a weak example and I suspect one of the regex gurus here will have a better date-verifying regex.  If you only care about checking for 8 numbers you could use `( \$\d{8})` for the third group.

Anyway the regular expression splits the string into 3 groups of characters that are surrounded by parentheses.  The first set is the beginning of the line up to but not including the space before the first dollar sign.  The second group contains the space in front of the first dollar sign and characters up to but not including the space in front of the last dollar sign.  The third group is the set of characters starting with the space in front of the last dollar sign followed by a literal '20' and 2 digits (year), a 0 or 1 followed by a digit (month), a 0 thru 3 followed by a digit (day) followed by the end of the string.  Returned are the first and last groups concatenated referenced by '\1\3'.

Caveat: Note that if you change the month of 09 to 99 the match will fail and if the match is not found the original string is returned so you have to be aware of this action.

Comment: Thanks.Just one doubt..date will be in 8 digits format for sure but it can be any date like 19950515 or 18810729 etc

Comment: Like I said the date test is not very strong. My example was to get you started.